# UIImagePickerController with camera source: video trimming doesn't work

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, camera

I am using `UIImagePickerController` to record a video with the `sourceType` set to `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera`.

I have set `allowsEditing` to true so that the video can be edited before the picker returns. But after I edit the video using the trimming interface and press "Pick", I only get back the original recording in the delegate, not the trimmed version. What am I doing wrong? I am using iPhone OS 3.1.3. I remember this used to work in an earlier version but it seems to be failing in the latest OS. Any help is appreciated?

By the way i confirmed that if the source of the video is `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum`, the trimming works in version 3.1.3. So trimming with source as the camera is failing. Interestingly with the camera-roll/photos-album as the source, a "Choose" button appears and soon after clicking it, the controller displays a message saying the "Video is being trimmed ... ". I don't get this message when using the camera source.

Here is a snippet of the code I am using to record a video using the camera source.

```
- (void) recordVideo {
   UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
   picker.delegate = self;
   picker.allowsEditing = YES;
   picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
   picker.mediaTypes =  [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
   picker.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh;

   [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
   [picker release];   
}
```

My delegate implementation is as follows:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *)info {

  [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  self.videoPath = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];
  ...
}
```

Thanks a lot,

kris.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this myself ... and found this post when looking for a solution.

looks like the only way around this is to copy the file to your app's directory, then open the UIVideoEditorController ...

Anyone know if this UIImagePickerController newly-captured video not being trimmed issue is a bug in the SDK, or are we doing something wrong?

Comment: It looks intentional: After the user edits a picked item—such as by cropping an image or trimming a movie—the URL continues to point to the original version of the picked item. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007069

Comment: No, it is not that simple. When picking an image, both the edited and original images are returned. And when picking a video with sorceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum, a trimmed video is returned. Observationally, whenever an untrimmed video is returned, the dict also contains @"_UIImagePickerControllerVideoEditingStart" and @"_UIImagePickerControllerVideoEditingEnd" keys with the trimmed start and stop time (in seconds). I guess that we have to look for these and do the trimming ourselves (if present)